# Ckeditor 5 classic in textarea in Laravel Liveware, the form will not be submitted

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-livewire, ckeditor5

I use Ckeditor 5 classic in textarea in Laravel Liveware, the form will not be submitted.
How can I solve this problem?

This form is bootstrap modal form. when i use ckeditor code in app.blade.php then the form are not submitted.

** Form Code**

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="createAppointment">
    <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="client_id">Client</label>
               <select wire:model.defer="state.client_id" id="client_id" class="form-control">
                @foreach($clients as $client)
                      <option value="{{$client->id}}">{{$client->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
               </select>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Date</label>
                   <div wire:ignore class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4" data-target-input="nearest" data-appointmentdate = "@this">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="appointmentDateInput" data-target="#datetimepicker4" />
                            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker4" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Time</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker3" data-target-input="nearest" data-appointmenttime = "@this">
                            <input type="text" id="appointmentTimeInput" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker3" />
                            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" wire:ignore>
                        <label for="note">Note</label>
                        <textarea wire.model.defer="state.note" id="note" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-dismiss="modal"
                    >
                        <i class="mr-1 fa fa-times"></i>
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="mr-1 fa fa-save"></i>
                        {{ $showEditModal == true ? "Update" : "Save" }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**javascript Code**

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/29.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
            ClassicEditor
                .create( document.querySelector( '#note' ) )
                .then( editor => {
                        console.log( editor );
                } )
                .catch( error => {
                        console.error( error );
                } );
        </script>
```

Comment: I'm unsure if the divs are correctly formatted, isn't missing a </div> for the modal-body? But besides that, there's some error on the console?
Also, this Ckeditor integration doesn't look that will work. When you type on the textarea the div will reload and probably the javascript ClassicEditor.create() will not be realoaded (so the textarea will miss its Ckeditor instance).

Comment: this Ckeditor doesn't need configure some plugin on create syntax code?